# Why is my program getting slower and slower?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, jvm

I'm using the program to send data from database to the Excel file . 
It works fine at the beginning and then becomes more and more slowly,finally it run out of the memory and the following error ocurrs: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space...".

The problem can be resolved by adding the jvm heap sapce.But the question is that it spends too much time to run out the program.

After several minutes,it finished a loop with 4 seconds which can be finished with 0.5 seconds at the beginning . I can't found a solution  to make it always run in a certain speed.

Is it my code problem?

Any clues on this?

Here is the code:

```
public void addAnswerRow(List<FinalUsers> finalUsersList,WritableWorkbook book){

   if (finalUsersList.size() >0 ) {
    try {
       WritableSheet  sheet = book.createSheet("Answer", 0);
       int colCount = 0;
       sheet.addCell(new Label(colCount++,0,"Number"));
       sheet.addCell(new Label(colCount++,0,"SchoolNumber"));
       sheet.addCell(new Label(colCount++,0,"District"));
       sheet.addCell(new Label(colCount++,0,"SchoolName"));
       sheet.setColumnView(1, 15);
       sheet.setColumnView(3, 25);

       List<Elements> elementsList = this.elementsManager.getObjectElementsByEduTypeAndQuestionnaireType(finalUsersList.get(0).getEducationType().getId(),     this.getQuestionnaireByFinalUsersType(finalUsersList.get(0).getFinalUsersType().getId()));

       Collections.sort(elementsList, new Comparator<Elements>(){

           public int compare(Elements o1, Elements o2) {

             for(int i=0; i< ( o1.getItemNO().length()>o2.getItemNO().length()?  o2.getItemNO().length(): o1.getItemNO().length());i++){
                  if (CommonFun.isNumberic(o1.getItemNO().substring(0, o1.getItemNO().length()>3? 4: o1.getItemNO().length()-1)) && !CommonFun.isNumberic(o2.getItemNO().substring(0, o2.getItemNO().length()>3? 4: o2.getItemNO().length()-1))){
                 return 1;
                  }
                 if (!CommonFun.isNumberic(o1.getItemNO().substring(0, o1.getItemNO().length()>3? 4: o1.getItemNO().length()-1)) && CommonFun.isNumberic(o2.getItemNO().substring(0,o2.getItemNO().length()>3? 4:o2.getItemNO().length()-1))){ 
                 return -1;
                 }  
                if ( o1.getItemNO().charAt(i)!=o2.getItemNO().charAt(i) ){

                    return   o1.getItemNO().charAt(i)-o2.getItemNO().charAt(i);
                 }
           }
           return  o1.getItemNO().length()> o2.getItemNO().length()? 1:-1;
       }});

       for (Elements elements : elementsList){
           sheet.addCell(new Label(colCount++,0,this.getTitlePre(finalUsersList.get(0).getFinalUsersType().getId(), finalUsersList.get(0).getEducationType().getId())+elements.getItemNO()+elements.getItem().getStem())); 
       }

       int sheetRowCount =1;
       int sheetColCount =0;

       for(FinalUsers finalUsers : finalUsersList){

          sheetColCount =0;

          sheet.addCell(new Label(sheetColCount++,sheetRowCount,String.valueOf(sheetRowCount)));
          sheet.addCell(new Label(sheetColCount++,sheetRowCount,finalUsers.getSchool().getSchoolNumber()));
          sheet.addCell(new Label(sheetColCount++,sheetRowCount,finalUsers.getSchool().getDistrict().getDistrictNumber().toString().trim()));
          sheet.addCell(new Label(sheetColCount++,sheetRowCount,finalUsers.getSchool().getName()));

          List<AnswerLog> answerLogList = this.answerLogManager.getAnswerLogByFinalUsers(finalUsers.getId());


          Map<String,String> answerMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

          for(AnswerLog answerLog :answerLogList ){
             if (answerLog.getOptionsId() != null)
             {
                answerMap.put(answerLog.getElement().getItemNO(), this.getOptionsAnswer(answerLog.getOptionsId()));
             }else if (answerLog.getBlanks()!= null){

                answerMap.put(answerLog.getElement().getItemNO(), answerLog.getBlanks());
             }else{

                answerMap.put(answerLog.getElement().getItemNO(), answerLog.getSubjectiveItemContent());  
             }   
          }
          for (Elements elements : elementsList){

             sheet.addCell(new Label(sheetColCount++,sheetRowCount,null==answerMap.get(elements.getItemNO())?"0":answerMap.get(elements.getItemNO())));

          }

         sheetRowCount++; 
       }

       book.write();
       book.close();

     } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (RowsExceededException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (WriteException e) {

      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

}
 }

Comment: (Continued from the comment below) You don't need to explain it in detail.. For example, "I am taking two sheets that both have a common key (studentId or something??) and joining them" or something. Then we can recommend you to use merge-sort to sort these sheets first, using disk space, and then you can iterate through both sheet without using bunch of memory...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Somewhere you are creating objects and retaining reachable references to them.

You are probably adding objects to a collection and never removing them... so the collection just grows until you run out of memory.  As you get close to the maximum heap size the garbage collector is over-taxed to find free memory to reorganize things and the program get exponentially slower the closer you get to the limit.

Also, it's possible you are forgetting to close some object(s) each time through, such as your workbook.

Comment: It sounds that it can't be avoid.Because it must create objects to hold the data from database and  the time when the GC work is unkown.
Also the Workbook is closed at the end:book.close()

Comment: The code is difficult to follow... can you explain briefly what you are trying to achieve? Then we might be able to see whether it (having a huge collection) really can't be avoided (If it really can't be avoided, you can still use the disk so don't worry..)

Comment: @Zwei: You might want to move your comment to the question... I don't think RedWolf will be notified if it's under my answer.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey The OP would have been notified if @Zwei had used @RedWolf :)

Comment: @Zwei:The code get a poor readability since I found that it difficult to explain it briefly,I'll check the code after  memory profile. Just now I only edits the code to make it neat.Thanks.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent, @Software Monkey, Thanks, this ("@") is neat :)

Answer (score 2):

I highly suspect that there is a memory leak on your program. Use profiler like JProfiler or YourKit to detect memory leak. Maybe you forgot to close the WritableWorkbook?

http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/current/docs/jxl/write/WritableWorkbook.html

Comment: The Workbook is closed at the end.I'm going to mark a memory test. :)

Answer (score 1):

When your application is running out of heap space, it will take more and more time in the GC trying to reclaim space before eventually giving up and throwing an OutOfMemoryError.  I recommend doing the following:

- add the `-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit` JVM option to cause the JVM to fail earlier when it is running out of memory.
- use a memory profiler to look for possible memory leaks
- if you cannot find any leaks, just increase the heap size.

If you still get slowdown effects with a bigger heap, the problem may be something to do with the algorithms being used.  In that case, you need to use an execution profiler to figure out where your application is spending most of its time.

[Theory: If your `addAnswerRow` is being called repeatedly, the problem could be related to repeatedly opening an Xcel spreadsheet file that is getting larger each with each `addAnswerRow` call.  It is possible that each time you open the file, it is being loaded into memory in its entirety.]

Comment: A excel file is created when the addAnswerRow() is called once.It's my false that I named the function as addAnswerRow().It should be called createAnswerExcel(). It's called repeatedly indeed.
I'll follow your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the *-verbose:gc* JVM option to easily check if the slowdown is caused by GC thrashing.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the heap size might help. You can try setting the min and max heap size by including -Xms and -Xmx arguments. The following command will set min heap size as 512 MB and max heap as 1024 MB.

java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m MyProgram